# Setting Up Multiple Event Responses using named functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scripting

I am trying to change this :

```
$( "p" ).on({
    "click": function() { console.log( "clicked!" ); },
    "mouseover": function() { console.log( "hovered!" ); }
});
```

To look like this :

```
$( "p" ).on({
    "click": fnOne(); },
    "mouseover": fnTwo(); }
});


function fnOne(){
    alert("click");
}

function fnTwo(){
    alert("click");
}
```

What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass function references as the values to the event name properties

```
$("p").on({
    "click": fnOne,
    "mouseover": fnTwo
});
```

In your code, there are syntax issues, also what you are trying to do is to invoke those functions and pass the value returned by those as the event handlers which is undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I will mark your post as answer in few minutes. Btw lets say for example I want to call `fnOne` and `fnTwo` both on `click` event. 

`"click": fnOne,fnTwo
    "mouseover": fnTwo`     wouldn't be correct of course. What would be correct?

Comment: @Arbaaz either you can create another function which will call these 2 functions.. http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lmmmt5eh/2/

Comment: Just one more question. I can turn off the event listener in the second example that you gave like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lmmmt5eh/4/

but lets say at some point i want to stop listing to fnTwo in this example http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Lmmmt5eh/2/  is it possible?